# Correct way to use UIViewControllerRepresentable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I usually use it this way because if I create a new object in `makeUIViewController` there are two objects in total. So instead of creating new object I return self. Do you think I am doing it right?

```
final class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MyViewController {
        return self
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyViewController, context: Context) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Representable must be a struct, the pattern is

```
struct MyView: UIViewControllerRepresentable { // << view

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> MyViewController {
        return MyViewController()  // create controller !!
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: MyViewController, context: Context) {}
}
```